# The import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, ssl, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have been trying to build the project taken from this link but facing issues:
https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request

Its giving the error : The import `cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory cannot be resolved`

i am also attaching the snapshot of the same[image]

[image]

I have been trying to build the project in eclipse,please help me rectify the error as after trying all options i am not getting any clue to resolve it.thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 3):

From version 1.4.9 onward, android-async-http depends on a repackaged version of Apache HTTP to ensure compatibility with future versions of Android.  You can get it [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cz.msebera.android/httpclient).

Comment: thanks ,your solution worked but now i have started getting this error in some of the files : import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory cannot be resolved.

Comment: @Pratswinz Googling a Java package name often leads you to the [Maven repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core) or some other download location for that library.